# saving scroll distance and passing it through the URL

Tags: php, javascript, html, scroll

I'm trying to create a link that when clicked is able to run a javascript function that counts how far down the page has been scrolled, then sends that value through the URL... i mostly work using php so im not very well versed n javascript

My Link

```
    <?php    
            echo '<a href="test.php?scroll=';
    ?>
            <script>
                   $(document).scrollTop();
            </script>
    <?php    
            echo '">add to cart
            </A>';
    ?>
```

Javascript function:

```
<script>
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        console.log($(document).scrollTop());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use link anchors?

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: no i want it to be seamless. the link will load a php script and then send the user back to that page

Comment: Why would an anchor doesn't achieve the same result?

Comment: anchor tags jump to a predefined location

Comment: You want visitors to click on a link, follow that link, jump back and then scroll the page to that link? 
If you give the link a unique id, you can add the redirect url with #<link_id> and the job gets done.

Comment: no the links runs a php script and then posts back to the previous page. the user shouldn't know that they left the page except at the moment the page jumps to the top...

Comment: sounds like you should do some ajax

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to update, dynamically, the data that you want to send when the user clicks. Samples here are HTML / javascript code, to give you the gist, but my JQuery is useless:

Using a form:

```
<form action="test.php" name="theForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="scroll" value="0" />
   <input type="button" value"Add to cart" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).scroll(
  function() {
    document.theForm.scroll.value = $(document).scrollTop();
  }
);
</script>
```

Scrolling triggers the JQuery event handler, which goes to the form and updates the value of the hidden field. When the user clicks add to cart, the scroll data, in the hidden field, is submitted.